# Issues connecting TVs as additional Windows 10 displays

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, tv

I am unable to get either of two TVs to connect to my Windows 10 setup. The televisions are **Westinghouse WD50FB1200** ([link](https://westinghouseelectronics.com/product/50-inch-fhd-tv-wd50fb1200/)) and the graphics card that I intend to run them with is the **Nvidia Quadro m4000**.

I have attempted to connect them using both a Displayport to HDMI cable and a Displayport to VGA converter, utilizing the HDMI and VGA ports on the Televisions respectfully.

Every cable I attempted to use was new, and I also replaced all of them to no results.

Any solutions? These displays were purchased specifically to be set up in this fashion, but I am unable to drive them.

Comment: Why didn't you get compatible card and TVs that don't require adapters to work together?

Comment: @harrymc DP to HDMI is not a live cable so I didnt think it would be an issue, I did not get to choose the Graphics card that was being used, and there are not a lot of TVs that support displayport and do not have "smart" functionality, which was required. Also this isn't really relevant to the question I asked.

Comment: True, I was just wondering. Have you checked: (1) The TV is set to use the right input port, (2) Use the [latest NVIDIS driver 392.37](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/143112/en-us), (3) Try [this advice](https://optima-systems.co.uk/fix-displayport-no-signal-windows-10/), (4) Are the displays visible in *Settings > System > Display*? If none of the above helps, is the symptom that there is no signal to the TV?

Comment: @harrymc I am actually unable to update the display drivers because this computer is currently not able to connect to the internet, that will be the next thing I do, however I don't have that much faith as the displays do not appear in System > Display unless I am using the VGA converter (because of how it works.) Displayport works for normal monitors, just not these TVs

Comment: You can download the driver installation on another computer.